# How to log in LBACSYS user?

Tags: database, oracle, database-connection, startup

```
SQL> CONN LBACSYS/12345@pdbaait;
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

SQL> CONN SYS/12345 AS SYSDBA
SQL> connected
```

How to log in using LBACSYS user? SYS user can log in as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Since `SYS` is a private user, Through using*

`SQL> conn / as sysdba` **or**

*from Operating System  `$ sqlplus / as sysdba`( by this command `Oracle Software` is invoked )*

*one can connect to the `SYS` user even without credentials(`SYS/12345`), and even 
the Oracle DB is not available, yet. Since it's operational user and needed for ignition of Database.*

*You need to `start up` your DB first to connect to an ordinary user.*